# Building Tic Tac Toe game to learn OOP, but my game board isn't updating

Tags: ruby, oop

These are incomplete codes, but it should at least update the game board until it fills up and error out. I don't know why its not updating the board. It definitely is registering my inputs as well as the computer's since the game does print my coordinates. Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Board
attr_reader :grid
  def initialize
    @grid = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) }
    @human = HumanPlayer.new
    @computer = ComputerPlayer.new
    @game = Game.new
  end

  def place_mark(pos)
    if (pos[0] < 0 || pos[0] > 2) || (pos[1] < 0 || pos[1] > 2)
      puts "Invalid coordinates! Please try again!"
      @game.play
    elsif empty?(pos)
      if @game.current_player == "human"
        puts "Player 1 goes: #{pos}"
        @grid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 'X'
      elsif @game.current_player == "computer"
        puts "Computer goes: #{pos}"
        @grid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = "O"
      end
      if winner
        puts "Congratulations! #{@game.current_player} wins!"
      else
        @game.switch_players!
      end
    else
      puts "Space Taken! Please Try Again!"
      @game.play
    end
  end

  def empty?(pos)
    @grid[pos[0]][pos[1]].nil?
  end

  def winner
    #Need to set winning combinations
    false
  end

  def over?
    false #for now, it will go until all spaces are filled. Still need to set end game condition.
  end

end


class HumanPlayer

  def display
    p Board.new.grid
  end

  def get_move
    puts "Please enter your the quadrant you wish to place your mark."
    pos = gets.chomp.scan(/[0-9]/).map!(&:to_i)
    Board.new.place_mark(pos)
  end

end


class ComputerPlayer

  def get_move
    x = rand(3).round
    y = rand(3).round
    Board.new.place_mark([x,y])
  end
end


class Game
  @@turn_tracker = 0
  def current_player
    @@turn_tracker.even? ? "human" : "computer"
  end

  def switch_players!
    @@turn_tracker += 1
    play
  end

  def play_turn
    if current_player == "human"
      HumanPlayer.new.display
      Board.new.place_mark(HumanPlayer.new.get_move)
    elsif current_player == "computer"
      ComputerPlayer.new.get_move
    end
  end

  def play
    play_turn until @@turn_tracker == 9 #Still need to set win conditions
  end

end

board = Game.new
board.play
```

- 1) Game Initiates with Game#new#play
- 2) #play will run the game until 9 turns have passed (temporary
  condition). It is passed to #play_turn
- 3) #play_turn figures out whose turn it is by using the

  ## current_player.
- 4) It is then passed to HumanPlayer.get_move or
  ComputerPlayer#get_move. These two will determine the moves of each
  player and pass it to Board#place_mark.
- 5) #place_mark will determine if the move is valid using #empty? If
  valid, it SHOULD update the grid. Then passes to the
  Game#switch_players!
- 6)#switch_players! will change the player and passes back to #play.
- 7) It should iterate through this loop.

Comment: Can you explain how it should work? And which method should update your board?

Comment: I added an explanation at the bottom of the post. I hope it clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

You always generate a new board, which then of course is again initalized with the starting position:

```
class HumanPlayer

  def display
    p Board.new.grid
  end
...
end
```

As you want to learn something, I don't present you a solution.

Comment: Been trying to fix it, but I give up. Can you give me an example of how to make it work? This is my first OPP build.